# CriteriaUpdate error

Tags: jpa, criteria

I wand update data in table **Registration** which relates OneToOne with table **User**

```
        CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaUpdate<User> query = qb.createCriteriaUpdate(User.class);
        Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);

        query.set(root.get(User_.registration).get(Registration_.attempts), 0);
        query.where(root.get(User_.id).in(userIDlist));
        em.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

So I have error

```
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) 2017-04-26 16:40:12 ERROR DEBUG_LOGGER:463 - ClientFacadeBean#resetSmsCount - {}
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6135] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Exception Description: Attribute name or expression passed as a first parameter to addUpdate method defines a field from a table that's not mapped to query descriptor. 
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Attribute name or Expression: [
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Query Key attempts
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)    Query Key registration
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)       Base QUERY OBJECT]
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Wrong field: [REGISTRATION.ATTEMPTS]
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(by.softclub.model.entity.User --> [DatabaseTable(USER)])]
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=User )
16:40:12,207 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
```

What I do wrong?

Add some info...

User entity is

```
...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Registration getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }
...
```

Registration entity is

```
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "registration")
    @TableGenerator(name = "registration", table = "SEQUENCES_TABLE",
            pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
            pkColumnValue = "registrationId",
            initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_CODE", nullable = false)
    private String messageCode;
    @Column(name = "CODE_EXPIRY", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date codeExpiry;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int attempts;
...
```

Comment: You seemingly want to update a field "registration.attempts", which is clearly not in the candidate entity. So set the CriteriaUpdate for the Registration class not the User class. Beyond that you have to include the actual entities

Comment: Add some info...